# Comparativo de Array() PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho as seguintes arrays:

```
$arrTag = "Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [id_pacote] => 7 [id_fornecedor] => [nome] => Salgados - 100 Un [valor_compra] => 100 [valor_venda] => 150 [descricao] => Pacote de Salgados com 100 unidades [created_at] => 2016-11-03 18:00:55 [updated_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [id_pacote] => 7 [id_fornecedor] => [nome] => Doces - 100 Un [valor_compra] => 50 [valor_venda] => 114 [descricao] => Pacote com 100 unidades de doces [created_at] => 2016-11-03 18:01:31 [updated_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [id_pacote] => 7 [id_fornecedor] => [nome] => Refrigerante - 10 un [valor_compra] => 50 [valor_venda] => 85 [descricao] => Pacote com 10 unidades de refrigerantes [created_at] => 2016-11-03 18:02:04 [updated_at] => ) )";
$arrBanco = "Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [valor_venda] => 150 [id] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [valor_venda] => 85 [id] => 3 ) )";
```

Preciso comparar se o id dentro da arrTag, é igual ao id dentro da arrBanco e colocar echo "checked";

Se resume em uma lista do banco de dados, onde eu tenho uma lista de itens (pacotes_itens) e virá marcado os itens que já foram comprados (pacotes_itens_comprados).

**HTML QUE SERÁ INSERIDO O CHECKED.**
Dentro do `input type="checkbox"`

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th width="50" class="text-center">#</th>
        <th>Item do Pacote</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th width="50" class="text-center"></th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    if(count($dados->detalhes_pacote)>0){
        foreach($dados->detalhes_pacote as $valor_pacote){                                      
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><?php echo $valor_pacote->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $valor_pacote->nome; ?></td>
            <td>R$ <?php echo number_format($valor_pacote->valor_venda, "2", ",", "."); ?></td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="itens[]" id="itens[]" class="checados" data-id="<?php echo $valor_pacote->id; ?>" value="<?php echo number_format($valor_pacote->valor_venda, "2", ",", "."); ?>|<?php echo $valor_pacote->id; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        }
    } else {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-center">Nenhum item foi adicionado a este pacote.</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: onde estão as referidas variáveis? arrtag, arrbanco...

Comment: Estão na questão acima... só não sei como verificar dentro das arrays, se o id de uma é igual ao id da outra

Comment: dentro do codigo maior, onde que fica ambas as variáveis?

Comment: O que você pretende com esse array representando dentro de uma `string`? Tá pensando em usar o `eval`?

Comment: Ponha o código que tem os _arrays_ na pergunta. Com aquelas duas strings não dá pra saber o que você quer. Precisa por as arrays de verdade, e não a representação visual delas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($arrBanco as $objBanco) {
  foreach ($arrTag as &$objtag) {

    if($objTag->id == $objBanco->id){
      // encontrei o $objTag, pode altera-lo diretamente aqui...
      $objTag->jaComprado = true;
    }

  }
}
```

Tive dificuldade para entender a relação entre "$dados->detalhes_pacote" e  "$arrTag $arrBanco"...